# Java multithreading: stop previous execution and start new

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a block of code, which should be executed only by one thread in time. If new thread arrives at this block - it should cancel previous execution and start a new one.

The example is a refreshing cache:

```
public void refreshCache() {
    //refresh cache can take up to 20 minutes
}
```

Of course, I can run this with `CompletableFuture`, store `Future` in an `AtomicReference` and cancel it when new thread arrives. But, that's the only option I have in mind.

Are there any best practices on how to handle such cases? What will be the solution if I want to run multiple instances of service?

Comment: Multiple instances of what service? What kind of external resources does `refreshCache()` access? How would you write your `CompletableFuture/AtomicReference` mechanism, and why do you feel it's not good enough for your purposes?

Comment: Re, "...can take up to 20 minutes." That's an _enormous_ amount of time. Why would starting over from scratch be a better option than waiting for the refresh-already-in-progress to finish? Is it because the work-in-progress is already obsolete? If a job that takes 20 minutes to complete can become worthless more often than every 20 minutes, then you have a serious architectural problem. Does the whole thing need to be done as a single atomic chunk? I would be looking for ways to break it up into smaller, independent pieces.

Comment: it updates the data in SQL DB, I can separate it to chunks and stop processing next chunks if it is interrupted, `CompletableFuture` will be a good fit for it. But if there are several microservices with this possibility - it may happen both of them are updating same tables.